# Envelope follower not smooth enough

Tags: filters, sampling, signal-analysis, lowpass-filter, signal-detection

With the following code, I get the "envelope" of a sound signal.
However in the "envelope" there are small oscillations (high frequency) : it is not smooth enough...

[image]

I imagine that it's possible to apply a low-pass to the "envelope signal" in order to  remove the high frequencies oscillations, but I also imagine it's probably better to do it directly by modifying this code :

```
double attack_coef = Math.Exp(Math.Log(0.01)/( 10 * 44100 * 0.001));   // 10 ms
double release_coef = Math.Exp(Math.Log(0.01)/( 100 * 44100 * 0.001));  // 100 ms
double envelope = 0.0;

for (int n = 0; n < file.Length; ++n) 
{
 double tmp = Math.Abs(x[n]);
 if (tmp > envelope)
  envelope = attack_coef * (envelope - tmp) + tmp;
 else
  envelope = release_coef * (envelope - tmp) + tmp;

 env[n] = envelope;
}
```

Do you have an idea for that ?

Comment: I tried by modifying `attack` and `release`, but with the values that I've tested, if I take higher values, it is smoother, but the peak doesn't reach the actual dBmax peak of my original signal...

Comment: Pretty much anything you do to remove the high frequency content will be a low-pass filter, even if it doesn't look like the canonical filter setup you are used to.

Comment: My first question would be: are you sure it isn't smooth enough? You're hardly ever going to get real-world signals that look like what you see in a textbook. In almost all cases, there will be some noise or jitter to your signal's structure, similar to what you showed above. What's important is whether those imperfections have any tangible effect on your application.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. It's not smooth enough because I use this envelope in order to modulate some other signal. I don't want small oscillations in the modulation...

Comment: Is there a "standard method" for a better envlope following ?
My envelope always starts with 0 (by design), so when I need to compute the `minimum` dB level of envelope, it is always 0. Of course I could compute the minimum of `env[n]` only for `n > 20 000` in order to avoid the 0 values for the envelope, but I was wondering if there are some better methods for computing the envelope (avoiding the 0 values at beginning + avoiding the oscillation problem)

Answer (score 2):

You are *already* just low-pass filtering the magnitude of the input signal. Right now, your envelope detection "circuit" is just a single-pole filter. Let $f[n]$ be the input to your system and, for simplicity sake, assume that `attack_coef` $=$ `release_coef` $ = a_1$. Then we can express the output $y$ of your system as follows:

$$y[n] = a_1 \left(y[n-1] - |f[n]|\ \right) + |f[n]|$$

Which we can rearrange as a transfer function $h$ as follows:
$$y = a_1 \left(y\,z^{-1} - |f|\right) + f$$
$$h = \frac{y}{|f|} = \frac{1 - a_1}{1 - a_1 z^{-1}}$$

You can use this information to either adjust your coefficients to get the desired cutoff frequency, or you could add another pole if you want a steeper roll-off.

Comment: Is there a "standard" method for envelope detection that does a little-better than the code that I mentionned ?
My main problems are : oscillations + the beginning of the envelope is close to 0 ... I need to compute the `minimum`  of the envelope => it is always 0 ;)

Comment: @JosBas Your minimum is always zero because you yourself define the starting point of your envelope to be zero. In most cases, this is the right thing to do. There are a number of ways you could work around this, but the one that makes the most sense is probably to figure out what the time constant is on your envelope detector and then throw out any envelope samples occuring before that time.  To "fix" the oscillations you can either add more poles to your current filter, or pass your envelope through an additional filtering stage.